# Merge same data in different lines (libreoffice)

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a scenario similar to this:

| Products | Amount sold |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| C | 1 |

I want to merge all lines with the same product, and sum it's sells, like this:

| Products | Amount sold |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 4 |

I use this to count the number of products someone has bought. If someone buys 5 B products, I add them to a new line. I don't think this is the best way to do it, but it should work for now.

Now I want to know how many products of each were sold.

Is there any magical function to help me?

Comment: Welcome! Just use https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/subtotaltool.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id521585182060496 or https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/guide/datapilot_createtable.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3148491